# Rotating labeling of grid in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, grids-graticules, rotate

I have a doubt I would like to know if you can rotate the labeling of the grid. Look at the image 1, the grid is rotated but the labeling is still perpendicular, I need the labeling to be parallel to the grid or inside it, as well as in the image 2 that was made with the autocad civil

image 1
[image]
image 2

[image]

Comment: Are you using ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro for this task?

Comment: I'm using arcgis 10.3 to do the labeling

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you labels are some type of coordinate, in which case you might able to [set the rotation amount using a numeric attribute field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/setting-label-rotation-using-a-numeric-field.htm). Otherwise one can also manually adjust layers by [converting them into annotations](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/converting-labels-to-annotation.htm), which makes them like a bunch of text boxes (that you can individually move, rotate, change the font size of, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The grid tools do not give you much control. If you could live with fewer labels, this would be easy enough to do occasionally: Turn your grid into a graphic from the first grid properties dialog, right click on the resulting graphic to ungroup the graphic, and then use drawing tools to select, move, and rotate a line of labels.